# WCF Service Trace - How to see the input and out data for a service call?

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe

We recently took over a Web services application which is written in WCF and C#. There is no client application to test the services on my local machine. All I could do is turning trace on in UAT. like below.

```
<system.diagnostics>
 <sources>
<source name="System.ServiceModel"
        switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true" >
  <listeners>
    <add name="xml"/>
  </listeners>
</source>
<source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
  <listeners>
    <add name="xml"/>
  </listeners>
</source>
<source name="myUserTraceSource"
        switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
  <listeners>
    <add name="xml"/>
  </listeners>
</source>
  </sources>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
  <sharedListeners>
<add name="xml"
     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
 </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

But when I open the trace file using Svcutil.exe, I do not see any real data elements that are being passed between systems. Where can I see the data? and is there any other/better way to run the application on my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can test the application using the WCF test client.
WCF test client is a GUI tool that allows you to send requests to a web service and view the response. It auto-generates the methods in your service from the service definition, so you won't have to bother with that.

You can typically find the WCF Test Client (WcfTestClient.exe) in the following location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE - Community may be one of "Enterprise", "Professional" or "Community" depending on which level of Visual Studio is installed.

For more information visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe

Comment: In WCF Test Client, it is asking me to enter each and every object separately and my XML input is pretty big. Is there any way where I can enter XML data and it populates the data in the client?

Comment: You just have to point the WCF Test Client to the service endpoint, and it will auto-generate the methods for you from the service definition. For example if you add this service: http://www.learnwebservices.com/services/hello?WSDL it will auto-generate the web service with two methods. You still have to add all the enpoints one by one. There is no way to add all endpoints in the WCF Test Client at once, as far as I know.

Comment: You can also run and debug the application by setting it as startup project in the solution explorer, and hitting f5. Visual Studio will auto-launch WCF Test Client with the generated service methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the bits to enable [messagelogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging) inside the serviceModel config.

Add this to your system.serviceModel config section in your web.config / app.config:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>  
    <diagnostics>  
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"  
                      maxMessagesToLog="3000"  
                      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="20000"
                      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"  
                      logMalformedMessages="true"  
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />  
    </diagnostics>  
    <!-- your bindings / services / behaviors are here --> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

Also set your switchvalue to Verbose

```xml
<source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"
        switchValue="Verbose">
  <listeners>
    <add name="xml"/>
  </listeners>
</source>
```